# Safely checking transaction origin account

Tags: solidity

I have the following scenario.

```
Contract A {
  mapping (address => bool) public allowed;
  mapping (address => uint) public userData;

  function doSomething(address _user) public returns(bool){
    if(allowed[_user]){ 
      userData[_user]++;
      return true;
    } else
      return false;  
  }
}

Contract B {
  function doSomethingWithA(){
     A contractA = A(_Aaddress);
     if(contractA.doSomething(msg.sender))
       // Do something
     else
       // don't
  }
}
```

Contract A holds a mapping of which users are allowed to interact with it.
Contract A has a function that should only be called by contract B.

ONLY the EOA interacting with B should be able to execute A's `doSomething()`.

In the current scenario, anyone could call `doSomething(address _user)` and pass an allowed `_user` to get a valid result.

I could `require(msg.sender == _user);` in `doSomething(address _user)`  but that would cause the function to fail as the msg.sender would always be contract B.

I know I could use tx.origin instead of msg.sender, but I was wondering if that would compromise the security of the contract.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any other way to solve this without using tx.origin?
2. If the only way is with tx.origin. What should I have in mind in order to prevent an attack related to the usage of tx.origin?

Answer (score 1):

> ONLY the EOA interacting with B should be able to get true from checkIfAllowed(address _user).

Why? What difference does it make?

> In the current scenario, anyone could call checkIfAllowed(address _user) and pass an allowed _user to get a valid result.

This is true, but I don't see why it's a problem. What's the attack you're trying to prevent? Everything on the blockchain is public, so anyone can always find out which users A will allow. So arbitrary accounts calling `checkIfAllowed` doesn't introduce any sort of security flaw.

From your simplified example, I assume the intent is that B doesn't let `doSomething` succeed unless the account calling into B is "allowed" by A. The current code appears to have that intended effect.

If there's some other goal, please elaborate on what it is.

Comment: I just updated the question and modified the code to make my intentions more clear. I want A's doSomething() to modify some state variables only if the caller EOA is allowed to do so. BUT, this function is not to be called directly from Contract A, it should only be called by another contract (In this case, Contract B).

Comment: I know the information is public, that is not an issue. The issue is that I want to prevent someone other than the EOA calling the function to modify the state, but that is done by first passing through contract B and in that case msg.sender will always be contract B.

Comment: What's special about contract B? Why not just (in contract A) `require(msg.sender == addressForContractB);`?

Comment: I'm essentially pushing back on the idea of "This should only happen if the EOA that started the transaction is X." `tx.origin` does that, but it's pretty much never really what you want. (For example, a malicious contract called by X could in turn call into A. X can mitigate that by reading the contract code he's calling into, but that's a somewhat weak mitigation.) If you want only X to be able to do something, let X call into contract A directly and _then_ call into contract B.

Comment: Imagine Contract A is a contract that generates promo codes. a promo code is generated by Contract A to be used only by a certain address A specifies.

Contract B is a store that wants to implement promo codes. So it would receive the call from the account, pass it to contract A, which will check if the user has been given allowed to use the promo code and if yes, it will mark it as used and return OK to the Store contract.  The user should never interact with contract A, but with the Store that implements such promo code.

Comment: The gist of it is that I would deploy contract A (promo code contract) and any other Store contract would be able to use it to check if a promo code has been issued to the person interacting with the Store.

Comment: User tries to buy something from Store and passes a promo code ID -> Store asks Promo Code Contract if that code ID exists and has been made available to the User (here's where tx.origin would be used) -> Promo Code verifies that the code has been issued to that user and marks the promo code as "redeemed" -> Promo Code contract returns true to Store, saying the code was validated and applied -> Store applies the promo code.

Comment: Okay, so B trusts A to be authoritative with regard to promo codes, and X (user) trusts B to honor a valid promo code. Further, A trusts B (everyone?) to mark promo codes as consumed. That last part confuses me a bit. What's the relationship between A and B? If B honors a promo code that A said was valid, is A then bound to later reimburse B in some fashion? What if X and B cut a deal so that B honors X's promo code but then doesn't mark it as redeemed so X can use it again at contract C? Is that okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70637/discussion-between-pabloruiz55-and-smarx).